# searching string to find indexes

Tags: python

I want to find all indexes of "a" item of my string, but it prints only the first one. What is the problem of this program:

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    for index in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[index] == c:
            print(index)

s = "parisa"
str_lookup_reverse(s, "a")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing the length of the string... So you're removing the last a making s = 'paris'

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    for index in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[index] == c:
            print(index)

s = "parisa"
str_lookup_reverse(s, "a")
```

This will solve your problem:

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    for index in range(len(s)):
        if s[index] == c:
            print(index)

s = "parisa"
str_lookup_reverse(s, "a")
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried it like this:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(s):
    if letter == c:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Have _you_ tried like this? (Hint: you probably mean `enumerate(s)`)

Comment: Damn I missed it :D

Answer (score 2):

You are using `len(s)-1`, which will not iterate over the full length of the string. You should use `len(s)`:

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    for index in range(len(s)):
        if s[index] == c:
            print(index)

s = "parisa"
str_lookup_reverse(s, "a")
```

To illustrate the problem, compare:

```
text='parisa'
for i in range(len(text)-1):
    print("%s, %s") % (i, text[i])
```

---

```
0, p
1, a
2, r
3, i
4, s
```

With:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print("%s, %s") % (i, text[i])
```

---

```
0, p
1, a
2, r
3, i
4, s
5, a
```

Answer (score 1):

Very close. Your loop is ending too soon, you need to do loop over the indices of the whole string:

```
for index in range(len(s))
```

instead of:

```
for index in range(len(s)-1)
```

which loops over everything but the last character, where your second `"a"` occurs. This means that your second `"a"` never gets reached.

Additionally, a more pythonic way is to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    for i, e in enumerate(s):
        if e == c:
            print(i)

s = "parisa"
str_lookup_reverse(s, "a")
```

Which also outputs what you want:

```
 1
 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned your issue with `for index in range(len(s)-1):`, which needs to be `for index in range(len(s)):`.

Now, here's an approach with `enumerate`:

```
[i for(i, v) in enumerate(s) if v == 'a']
```

e.g.

```
In [54]: s = "parisa"

In [55]: [i for(i, v) in enumerate(s) if v == 'a']
Out[55]: [1, 5]
```

**As a function:**

```
def findidx(string, char):
    return [i for(i, v) in enumerate(string) if v == char]
```

e.g.

```
In [56]: def findidx(string, char):
   ....:     return [i for(i, v) in enumerate(string) if v == char]
   ....: 

In [57]: findidx(s, "a")
Out[57]: [1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the `index` by wrapping the `String(s)` with `enumerate()` as shown below.

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    index_list  = []
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == c:
            index_list.append(index)
            # print(index)
    return index_list


s           = "parisa"
index_list  = str_lookup_reverse(s, "a") 
print(index_list)        ## PRINTS: [1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just go through the characters like this -

```
def str_lookup_reverse(s, c):
    ind = 0
    for eachChar in s:
       ind += 1 
          if eachChar == c:
          print(ind)

s = "parisa" 
str_lookup_reverse(s, "a")
```

Comment: `ind` is not defined.